How to Extract table data from Website using Python RPA Software?
I am trying to scrape a website using cards on Python RPA software. I need to extract whole table and store it in a Excel file. I am trying to use below cards but not getting results.

web find elements
2.For.Each
Web Element Get Attributes

please suggest what to do ?
